# SQLite not accepting unique command

Tags: python, sqlite, flash

Python/Flask:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, password TEXT)')
print('Table created')
```

Then in another method

```
def create_user(email, hashedpw):
    try:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?)', (email, hashedpw))
        conn.commit()
        return "works"
    except:
        print(str(sqlite3.Error))
        return None
```

Even if I input the same email 10 times it still records the data in the database and doesn't give an error. I clearly set it to `UNIQUE` then why isnt it working?

Comment: have you tried marking it as a primary key?

Comment: @EmreTürkiş, it still creates the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax looks good so only explanation that comes to mind is:

You already have a table named `users` in your database which doesn't have the `UNIQUE` constraint and since you are using `IF NOT EXISTS`, that table remains as it is.